# Get a DropDownList item from a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm using Visual Basic with ASP.NET. I have a GridView table with a DroDownList column and I need a way to get the selected item from it. Now I'm using an ImageButton in order to get the selected item from the DropDownList to pop-up as a message box. I already know how to get an integer from a boundfield. However, using the same code to get the DropDownList item won't work.
This is a snippet from my code:

ASP code:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Case#" HeaderText="Case#" ReadOnly="True" />

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Surgery Time"> 
        <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="Time_Slot" runat ="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select...</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">8:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">9:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">10:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="4">11:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="5">12:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="6">1:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="7">2:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="8">3:00</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="9">4:00</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList> 
        </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField> 

<asp:ButtonField buttontype="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/check.jpg" commandname="Accept" HeaderText="Accept" SortExpression="Accept" />
```

Visual Basic code:

```
Sub GridView_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Accept" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        'This value is retrieved from the databound
        Dim contactCell As TableCell = selectedRow.Cells(0)
        Dim contact As String = contactCell.Text
        'however here it is not retrieved from the dropdownlist
        Dim contactCell2 As TableCell = selectedRow.Cells(1)
        Dim contact2 As String = contactCell2.Text
        MsgBox("case number is" + contact + "time is" + contact2)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
If e.CommandName = "Accept" Then
    Dim index = e.CommandArgument
    Dim timeSlot = CType(gridview1.Rows(index).FindControl("Time_Slot"), DropDownList)
    Dim selectedTimeSlot = timeSlot.SelectedValue
End If
```